# Give border to combined fieldset

Tags: css, reactjs, fieldset

I've tried making a fieldset with the react app but it seemed difficult so i managed to make it look like with some css, and now i'm pretty curious about how to border the comlpete box just like this
[image: image1]

```
  <div class="fieldset">
    <div class="legend">Text</div>
    Text2
  </div>
```

Customised Styles:

```
  .fieldset{
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 30px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .legend{
    font-size: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -8%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    background: #fff;
  }
```

Comment: Please show us your code as we can only guess how 'the complete box' is made up of element(s);

Comment: @AHaworth here!

Answer (score 0):

this way you can goes near your goal.
Hope it's work for you.

```css
.fieldset{
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 30px;
            margin: 100px 30px 30px;
            position: relative;
            font-size: 45px;
            width: 200px;
            border-radius: 10px;

          }
          .legend{
              position: absolute;
              width: fit-content;
              top: -74px;
              left: 0;
              right: 0;
              margin: 0 auto;
              padding: 10px;
              border: 1px solid #000;
              border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
              border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
        }
```

```html
<div class="fieldset">
   <div class="legend">Title</div>
   Content
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but this is not what i'm expecting